# Oracle SQL Developer, using dynamic SQL in function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following script which contains a function named **'myFunction'**. (declaration of types named **rowValueTmp** and **rowValueTable** are also attached for your information) Basically, I need to use a table name as an input parameter for **myFunction**. I found that I need to use dynamic SQL in order to use the table name as a parameter (Please correct me if there are alternative ways to do this). So the following code is what I have tried so far.

```
create or replace type rowValueTmp as object (
    month number,
    year number
);
/    
create or replace type rowValueTable as table of rowValueTmp;
/        
create or replace FUNCTION myFunction (TABLENAME in VARCHAR2) 
    return rowValueTable as
      v_ret   rowValueTable;
    begin
      execute immediate '
      select rowValueTmp(month, year)
      bulk collect into v_ret
      from '||TABLENAME;    
      return v_ret;
    end myFunction;
/
select * from table(myFunction('SCHEMA.TEST'));
```

But, this code gives me an error, and I assumed that this error is occurred because of using '**bulk collect**' in **execute immediate** block.

```
ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
```

If I replace the content of **execute immediate**  as the following, the above script is working..

```
select rowValueTmp(month, year)
bulk collect into v_ret
from SCHEMA.TEST;
```

**Question**
1] Is there any way(rather than Dynamic SQL) that I can use a table name as an input parameter for **myFunction**? 
2] If I am not allowed to use **bulk collect** in **execute immediate** block, what do you suggest?

Comment: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM bulk_collect_test' BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;`, http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_dynamic.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return values from `execute immediately` into a `bulk collect`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction (tablename IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN rowvaluetable AS
   v_ret rowvaluetable;
   v_table VARCHAR2 (61) := DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (tablename);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
      select rowValueTmp(month, year)
      from ' || v_table
      BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret;

   RETURN v_ret;
END myfunction;
/
```

In the interest of an abundance of caution, I'd recommend using `DBMS_ASSERT` to validate the table parameter as well (as shown).